# How to force VS Code to always use the same level of indentation for ALL files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have problems with indentations of VS Code.

Different file types, different indentations.

Same file types, different indentations. Completely unpredictable.

For example, two `docker-compose.yml` files. One has 2-space indentation. The other 4-space indentation.

How can I force VS Code to use the same indentation, for **ALL** files, regardless of type.

Comment: It depends on how the file was saved, you can reformat the files based on your settings. For a project, you can use the .editorconfig file

Comment: @FadiHania I added a `.editorconfig` file to my project. But on my save, or code formatting, the indentation of files do not change. I specified the indentation for all files to be 4 spaces in the `.editorconfig` file.

Comment: I've added an answer with more details on the options you have for formatting in VS Code

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code to format your code you have few options. Format manually, right click and select format document or **SHIFT+ALT+F**. You can also use VS Code settings like format on save (`editor.formatOnSave`), to enable autoformat on saving files.

You have project based formatting settings using `.editorconfig` file in the root of project. Install [EditorConfig for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) extension to enable that. The other option would be to use Prettier, check [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension. Follow, extensions description for details on how to configure your formatting settings for each.